# nodejs expressjs app. How deploy to a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to deploy my nodejs and express applicaton to a server, is working fine on localhost, to start it I have to execute the `npm start` or `node index.js` command. I uploaded all files including node_modules to the external server. My question is, how do I execute it or make it run? The domain and everything is working, but when I enter the web page I only see the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** dump your application into a directory that an existing webserver will use to serve up the source code directly.

**Do** put the code somewhere else and run it with Node. Consider wrapping the command to run it with a tool like pm2 which can restart it if it crashes, rotate log files, and start it when the server reboots.

**Either:**

- Change the port the Express application runs on to port 80 (or 433 if you have support for HTTPS in it) and use it **instead** of your existing HTTP server (making sure it listens on externally facing network interfaces) *or*
- Configure your HTTP server to act as a reverse proxy for your Express application (in which case the Express application is better off listening only on the localhost loopback interface).

Comment: Okay yes, but how do I run the application IN the server. I don't think the server has ssh enabled for users. It's a personal server that I have to upload the application to

Comment: Generally speaking, if you can't get SSH access and want to deploy Node.js applications: Find a different server.

Comment: Okay I have ssh now. Can I do an npm start? When I do so this gives me an error.